# simple RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, mod-rewrite, sef

OK, it sounds simple, it looks simple and it weighs simple. But it's not.
I can't for the life of me get this working.

Let's say I have this URL structure:

> http://www.test.com/%action%[/%param1%/%paramX%]

I need to redirect (actually I want a REWRITE) to:

> http://www.test.com/index.php?option=com_%action%&param=[%param1%,%paramX%]

For example:

> http://www.test.com/product/25/allproducts/food/cakes/cheesecake

Becomes:

> http://www.test.com/index.php?option=com_product&param=25,allproducts,food,cakes,cheesecake

Ideas? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont mind to have this kind of parameters:

```
http://www.test.com/index.php?option=com_product&param=25/allproducts/food/cakes/cheesecake
```

you can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*) /index.php?option=com_$1&param=$2
```

it should work, but i havent check it ;)

Comment: This pretty much answer my question. I'll of course test it out, thanks for the heads up!